# AppleTV 4 Podcast App Slow Playback

Tags: appletv

After using a Harmony 520 remote with the new AppleTV 4 Podcast app, all the podcasts now playback in slow motion. Rebooting the AppleTV does not solve the problem. It appears that the Universal Remote somehow triggered a non-advertised slow playback feature.

No amount of finger mashing on the Harmony Remote or the AppleTV remote manages to reset this.

Anybody else stumble into this bug and find a solution back to normal speed other than resetting the entire AppleTV to factory defaults?

Comment: Having exact same issue. With my Harmony One. Unfortunately using the AppleTV remote did not correct the issue. All Podcasts are playing in slo-mo but pitch corrected. I don't want to reset my AppleTV but it might be my only alternative. Does anyone have any other ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally it seems that the tvOS 9.2.1 update cleared this problem up on my AppleTV 4.

Answer (score 0):

Solution for me was to just use the Apple remote one time to get it back on track. Harmony works properly now.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What exactly did you do with the Apple Remote to reset things?  Simple use of the Apple remote does not reset the playback speed for me.